# Setting up Yubikey for GnuPG on Linux Mint: Unsupported certificate

Tags: linux, gnupg, openpgp, yubikey

I am trying to set up my Yubikey 4 for GnuPGP following [the Yubico documentation](https://www.yubico.com/support/knowledge-base/categories/articles/use-yubikey-openpgp/#configure). I plugged in my Yubikey and it is recognized:

```
$ lsusb
...
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1050:0407 Yubico.com 
...
```

However, when running any `gpg2` commands in order to edit the key or see its status I get an error message about an "Unsupported certificate".

```
$ gpg2 --card-edit

gpg: selecting openpgp failed: Unsupported certificate
gpg: OpenPGP card not available: Unsupported certificate
gpg/card> q

$ gpg2 --card-status
gpg: selecting openpgp failed: Unsupported certificate
gpg: OpenPGP card not available: Unsupported certificate
```

Here is some information on my distro.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa
Release:    17.3
Codename:   rosa
```

I just got my Yubikey and its the first them that I am trying to use it. So I've never written anything to it before. Does anyone know what the problem could be? Am I missing any packages?

Comment: I have a yubikey 4 nano, and I remember needing to create a key and then placing it on the key to be read, by itself its just a crypto chip. But it can be loaded with certificates. But I'm not 100% sure about this anymore so I'm going to clear it out and do a bit of research, I'll get back to you on this one.

Comment: @Nalaurien, I am already getting stuck at the step that is supposed to be the preparation for placing a key on the Yubikey. It seems that it is not recognized as a smart card but only as a keyboard :(

Comment: Is the `pscd` service running?

Comment: No, its not. How do I start it?